# i was trying to make fragments for the firsr time in android and i am having this error at transactionmanager.add(android.R.id.content,home)

Tags: android, fragment, transactionmanager

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FragmentManager fr=getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmenttransaction=fr.beginTransaction();
        fragmentHome home = new  fragmentHome();
        fragmenttransaction.add(android.R.id.content,home);
        fragmenttransaction.commit();`
```

in this main activity i have used android.app library for for
 fragment manager and fragmentTransaction ,but it is still giving an
 error at `fragmentTransaction.add` that The method `add(int, Fragment)` in
 the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments 
`(int,fragmentHome)`      what to do , how to avoid that?

and this is my fragment class

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class fragmentHome extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment,container,false);
    }


}
```

`

Comment: Post full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Change your activity to `Fragment Activity`.

**Extend it to `FragmentActivity`.**

**Do this.**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
```